# Updating parent state from child components not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-component

I was going through react [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) when I struck upon an example which updates the parent component through child component callbacks. I was able to understand how the flow works. However, when I tried to optimize the code further it failed to update the component via callbacks.

**The Original Code:**

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/QKzAgB?editors=0010

**My code change:**

```
    class LoginControl extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {isLoggedIn: false};
    this.button = <MyButton message="Login" onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
  }

  handleLoginClick() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
  }

  handleLogoutClick() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
  }

  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      this.button = <MyButton message="Logout" onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      this.button = <MyButton message="Login" onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
        {this.button}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function UserGreeting(props) {
  return <h1>Welcome back!</h1>;
}

function GuestGreeting(props) {
  return <h1>Please sign up.</h1>;
}

function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}

class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.message=props.message;
    this.click=props.onClick;
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <button onClick={this.click}> 
        {this.message}
    </button>  
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <LoginControl />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: codepen link seems to be working to me. what error are you seeing?

Comment: The code is working... Please include the error you're getting on your question.

Comment: codeopen link works correctly. If you cut paste my code and then try to click on the button displayed, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the main problem here is that you are trying to assign to many things to "this".
React does not track changes and re-renders when component's method or properties changes.
try to avoid this pattern and use state and props directly.
Only changes to state or props will cause a component to re-render.
In you situation you can look at this code:

```
   class LoginControl extends React.Component {


     state = {isLoggedIn : false}

  handleLoginClick = () => {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
  }

  handleLogoutClick = () => {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
  }

  button = () => {

    const message = this.state.isLoggedIn ? "Logout" : "Login";
    const onClick = this.state.isLoggedIn ? this.handleLogoutClick : this.handleLoginClick;
    return <MyButton message={message} onClick={onClick} />
  }

  render() {


    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} />
       {this.button()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function UserGreeting(props) {
  return <h1>Welcome back!</h1>;
}

function GuestGreeting(props) {
  return <h1>Please sign up.</h1>;
}

function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}

class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.message=props.message;
    this.click=props.onClick;
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <button onClick={this.props.onClick}> 
        {this.props.message}
    </button>  
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <LoginControl />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. That works. However, I did not understand why the original code failed. I tried adding console.log statements everywhere through the code path with my changes. It seemed that LoginControl.render is getting called correctly with the change. In such case, shouldn't the button variables get updated, as we are re-assigning it a new value inside the LoginControl.render?

Comment: maybe this will make it a bit clearer. you can use your code as it is if you will change your render function to 

 render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = () => <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      button = () => <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
        {button()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}